# Can I maintain vb.net windows form designer code in .vb?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Can I maintain vb.net windows form designer code in .vb?

i.e I wanted to ask whether I can maintain only one .vb file for both form design and logic part, instead of having one designer.vb for form design part and .vb file for logic part?

Comment: Yes,  you may put all designer related code directory into initialize method and move the initialize method into .vb file. The .vb and desiger files are created separately to keep the auto generated and custom code separate/clean but you can combine as per will.

Comment: The designer still supports .NET 1.x code, back when the Partial keyword did not yet exist.  Lots of ways to fumble this, be sure to have a good backup.  Click the Show All Files toolbar button in the Solution Explorer window to get started, delete the Designer.vb file after you copy/pasted the code.  Treat whomever is going to maintain your code some day as a homicidal maniac that knows where you live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a functional sample:

_
    Partial Class Form1
        Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

```
    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub Intiialize()

        'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.

        InitializeComponent()


    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    End Sub
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.Text = "Form1"
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Partial keyword is not needed if it's all in one file.